# Expansion of an analytic function in the unit disk

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, power-series

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Suppose that $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_kz^k$ is an analytic function in $\mathbb{D} = \{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$. Prove that $F(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{c_k}{k!}z^k$ is an entire function such that $|F(z)|\leq Me^{2|z|}$ in the whole complex plane for some constant $M$.

**Progress:** Since $f$ is analytic in $\mathbb{D}$, then the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_kz^k$ converges for all $z\in\mathbb{D}$. In particular, $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{c_k}{2^k}$ converges. It follows that the sequence $\left( \frac{c_k}{2^k}\right)_{k\geq 0}$ converges to $0$, so it is bounded. Let $M$ be a constant such that $\left|\frac{c_k}{2^k}\right|\leq M$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Hence, $$F(z) = \left| \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{c_k}{k!}z^k \right| \leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{|c_k|}{k!}|z|^k \leq M\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2|z|)^k}{k!} = Me^{2|z|}.$$

It is only missing to prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{c_k}{k!}z^k$ converges for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Use the bound $|c_k| \leq M2^{k}$ and apply ratio test.

Comment: @geetha290krm With the ratio test we obtain the limit $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left| \frac{c_{k+1}z^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}\cdot\frac{k!}{c_kz^k} \right| = \lim_{k\to\infty} \left| \frac{c_{k+1}}{c_k} \right|\frac{|z|}{k+1}$$ for a fixed $z\in\mathbb{C}$. How can I use the bound?

Comment: You also have $\limsup_k \sqrt[k]{|c_k|} \le 1$. Evaluate  $\limsup_k \sqrt[k]{|c_k| \over k!} $.

Comment: @geetha290krm Can you tell me if the following argument is correct? Since $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{c_k}{2^k}$ converges, the ratio test implies that $\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{2}\left|\frac{c_{k+1}}{c_k}\right| \leq 1$. Applying this to the limit that I wrote in the previous comment, we have that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{c_{k+1}}{c_k}\right| \frac{|z|}{k+1}\leq  \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{2|z|}{k+1} = 0 < 1.$$ Therefore, the series converges for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Don't apply ratio test to the original series. Apply the bound to get rid if $c_k$ and then apply ratio test to the new series.

Comment: You got a bound $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{|c_k|}{k!}|z|^k\le Me^{2|z|}$. This implies that $F(z)$ converges absolutely, and thus it converges for any $z$.

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy-Hadamard,  we have $$r=\limsup _{k\to\infty}\dfrac 1{\lvert \dfrac {c_k}{k!}\rvert ^{\frac 1k}}=\dfrac{\limsup_{k\to\infty}(k!)^{\frac1k}}{\limsup_{k\to\infty}\lvert c_k\rvert^{\frac1k}} =\dfrac {\infty}1=\infty.$$